# Double line spacing

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I would like to typeset a draft of my document with double linespacing so that my collaborators have space to write in their edits (with a pen).  How do I do it?

Comment: While for your case it doesn't seem to be crucial, this is a highly interesting question on the same topic: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package does it for you, but it turns doublespacing off within footnotes and floats like `figure` and `table` captions. That's usually desired.

But if you don't want to use `setspace`, perhaps because of the mentioned reason, you could use the command `\linespread`, for instance:

```
\linespread{1.5}
```

A package may be preferred over such a command though.

Comment: \linespread is also useful for fonts with large x-height (large lower case letters) to avoid the visual appearance of cramped pages. E.g. when using the Palatino font (\usepackage{mathpazo}), \linespread{1.05} is appropriate.

Comment: Why would a package be preferred over `\linespread`?

Comment: According to this: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=linespace  "_setspace_ switches off double-spacing at places where even the most die-hard official would doubt its utility (footnotes, figure captions, and so on); it’s very difficult to do this consistently if you’re manipulating `\baselinestretch` yourself."

Comment: Also, as explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30114/7262, `setspace` package adjusts the factors correctly for 10pt/11pt/12pt documents, which would be messier and easy forget if you use `\linespread` directly.

Comment: In my case, `\linespread` worked for some elements, but to change spacing in the document body I had to use `\linespacing`.

Comment: Can I use `linespread` just for two lines but not as default for the entire document?

Comment: @CGFoX I remember `\linespread`  is for the entire document.

Answer (score 241):

Simple: put

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
% or:
%\onehalfspacing
```

into your preamble. ([TeX-FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespace) advises for `setspace` and against `doublespace`.)

Comment: Provide additionally the option doublespacing: `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`.

Comment: again, one needs to make sure he/she knows what he/she meant by "double linespacing", doublespacing, or anything that is called slightly different and means different things, or called identical and means different things, and read this topic on [doublespacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean).

Comment: If somebody uses the `memoir` class, use `\DisemulatePackage{setspace}` before `\usepackage{setspace}`. Taken from: http://greengabbro.net/2009/02/15/line-spacing-with-the-latex-memoir-class-why-doesnt-setspacesty-work/

Comment: I found this to be the best answer. Here also a link to wikibooks on the topic of line spacing: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Line_Spacing

Answer (score 22):

The simplest possible way is probably by using the plain TeX macro `\openup`

E.g. if you want double line spacing, add a single line-height to the line spacing (1em) using:

```
\openup 1em
```

(don't use any braces around the argument, the macro takes its argument as if you had written \openup=1em, i.e. an assignment of a dimension).j

Following that macro's invocation all lines will have a single line's height extra to separate them, later on you can revert this effect by giving the negative argument:

```
\openup -1em
```

This macro works by increasing (`\advance`) the three parameters (`\lineskip`, `\baselineskip` and `\lineskiplimit`) that govern line spacing by the given amount.  It's defined in `plain.tex` if you want to have a look at it.

Comment: Or you can write \baselineskip=2\baselineskip directly

Comment: So for small portions of text, say a single table field, this method is ok and setspace would be overkill, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

**How can I change the spacing in my LaTeX document?**

To double space a LaTeX document, you should include the line

```
\usepackage{setspace}
```

after your `\documentclass` line.

Before your `\begin{document}` command.

```
\doublespacing
```

will make the text of the whole document double spaced, but footnotes, figures, and tables will still be single-spaced.

For one-and-a-half spacing, use the command

```
\onehalfspacing
```

To make a target part of the text single-spaced, you can place the text inside the following commands

```
\begin{singlespace}

\end{singlespace}
```

You can also set the spacing to be something other than double-spaced. For
example, if you wanted to have one-and-a-quarter spacing between lines,
use the line

```
\setstretch{1.25}
```

before your `\begin{document}` command, and after the `\usepackage{setspace}` line.

SOURCE - http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907092

I did not write this, but this helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to try

```
\setstretch{2}
```

Comment: Maybe? Please see [Why is the `\linespread` factor as it is?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30073/5764)