# Finely control line spacing when already using the setspace package?

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I'm using [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) to double-space an article (as it's widely known, this package behaves more intelligently than `\linespread`, [Double line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing) alread covers the details).

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

However, I'd like to finely adjust the "double" spacing so I can control the overall length of the paper. If I use `\linespread`, I go back to the less intelligent mechanism. Is there a way to fine tune what the `setspace` package does?

My question is specific to the `article` and, perhaps, `report` document classes. I'm saying this because some googling found some [tricks](http://greengabbro.net/2009/02/15/line-spacing-with-the-latex-memoir-class-why-doesnt-setspacesty-work/) specific to the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In addition to the familiar `\onehalfspacing` (etc.) commands and `\begin{onehalfspace}...\end{onehalfspace}` (etc.) environments, the `setspace` package includes a `\setstretch{baselinestretch}` command that can help you out, or a `\begin{spacing}{nnn}...\end{spacing}` environment. Set the spacing factor number, `nnn` to, say, `1.85` or whatever your situation needs.  See the documentation in the comments in `setspace.sty` for more details.