# Longtable and modified \footnoterule

Tags: footnotes, longtable, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the footnote line (thickness, length)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21913/how-can-i-change-the-footnote-line-thickness-length)

I want to modify the `\footnoterule` and still be able to use `longtable` but the following code doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace*{0.3cm}\noindent\rule{2.5cm}{0.4pt}\vspace*{0.3cm}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
Text\footnote{Footnote}
\begin{longtable}{c}
N.\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\            
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this definition:

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{0.3cm}\hrule width 2.5cm\vspace*{0.3cm}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're just after shortening the horizontal length (actually, the rule *width*) of `\footnoterule`, here's how;

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width2.5cm
  \kern2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
Text\footnote{Footnote}
\begin{longtable}{c}
N.\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\\            
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\footnoterule` was taken directly from the [`article` document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls), which defines it as

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
```