# footmisc in beamer citations get lost

Tags: beamer, citing, footmisc

Since I want to take advantage as much as possible of the space in a poster I'm making I want to make the footnotes (that include citations) appear continuous (in one line). After searching I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line) that says that I can achieve that using the `footmisc` package.

The problem is that when I use it, my footnotes disappear. Consider the following example code. If you remove the `\usepackage[norule,para]{footmisc}`, the footnotes appear properly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[norule,para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
        \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}
          \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
            \begin{block}{Test}
              this is some test text\footnotemark
            \end{block}}
        \end{minipage}
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
    \footcitetext{osborne-rubinstein}
    %Second Column %
    \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
      test\footnotemark
    \end{column}
    \footcitetext{test}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there some problem with the `footmisc` package and the the `beamer` class or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can't use both packages together. `beamer` has its own `\footnote` definition and you are destroying it if you load `footmisc`.

Comment: Any idea then on how to make footnotes appear in line in beamer? Or is it impossible?

Comment: I would probably simply fake the para look. E.g. `\setcounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{osborne-rubinstein, \textsuperscript{2}test}`

Comment: Using `\cite` inside `\footnotetext` instead of `\footcitetext` and what you said worked. Also using the answer from this post (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21913/how-can-i-change-the-footnote-line-thickness-length) I managed to make the line disappear. Cheers mate. You should change your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use both packages together. `beamer` has its own `\footnote` definition and you are destroying it if you load `footmisc`.

I would probably simply fake the para look. E.g.

```
\setcounter{footnote}{1} 
\footnotetext{osborne-rubinstein, \textsuperscript{2}test}
```