# Multiple citations as footnotes in one line in beamer presentation style

Tags: beamer, citing, footnotes

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/footnotes-on-the-same-line) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69292/footmisc-in-beamer-citations-get-lost), for slides with a lot of citations appearing in footnotes, can I have multiple "author, year" citations on the same line, e.g.:

```
1 name year 2 name year 3 name year 4 name year ....
```

Rather than having it:

```
1 First footnote
2 Second footnote
3 Etc.
```

I know that `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}` does not work as `beamer` has its own footnote style. But Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291094/multiple-citations-as-footnotes-in-one-line-in-beamer-presentation-style

Comment: Without having a MWE and/or knowing how you cite your works, if you use biblatex/bibtex/manual citations this is hard to answer.