# Getting footcite citations to display on the same line in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

How would I go about getting `footcite` citations to be displayed on the same line, for instance separated by a semicolon? I would like the footnotes to display something like:

$^{1}$Smith, The Title; $^{2}$Smith2, The Title2

Here is a minimal example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author="John Smith",
  title="The title",
  year=1099,
  publisher="nobody",  
}
@book{test2,
  author="John Smith2",
  title="The title2",
  year=10992,
  publisher="nobody",  
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Text \footcite{test}
  \item Text2 \footcite{test2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: Normally one would say `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`, but according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69292/35864 that doesn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For other documentclasses this problem can be solved with the `footmisc` package. Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, you can not use both `beamer` and the `footmisc` package together, because `beamer` has its own `\footnote` definition.

Rather we can simply do a workaround and cite the works in a normal footnote:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author="John Smith",
  title="The title",
  year=1099,
  publisher="nobody",  
}
@book{test2,
  author="John Smith2",
  title="The title2",
  year=10992,
  publisher="nobody",  
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Text \footnotemark
  \item Text2 \footnotemark
  \setcounter{footnote}{1} 
  \footnotetext{\cite{test}, \textsuperscript{2}\cite{test2}} 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

from this you get

[image]

Comment: @samcarter I thought that solution was the not the one. But undeleted it. As a side note, I never knew one can see the deleted answer :D

Comment: +1 I think this workaround is the best one can get without seriously redefining things. The missing title in your original image might be caused by not running biber? -- however in principle your code works fine and I updated the image (With enough reputation one is allowed to see deleted posts, so just keep posting nice answers and you'll see them too :)

Comment: @samcarter Nice, good to know. I think that was the `biber` issue --> yes I did not run it. Still a beginner.

Comment: I reformulated the first paragraph a bit, because `\footcite` is from the biblatex package and not from footmisc. Please feel free to undo the edit.

Comment: @samcarter that is completely fine! No issues. The story looks more simple now.

Comment: Is there any way to do it automatically, not with manual imitation of footnotes?

Comment: @ Juda Ronen if you have a follow-up question, please post it as new instead.

Comment: Using this with `footfullcite` instead of `cite` returns a parenthesis `( )` surrounding the cite. Does anyone know why? If using `footfullcite` directly no parenthesis appears (also the parenthesis for the year is now changed for a square bracket). If i use `cite` as in the code here then it just returns the number of the citation, not the citation itself.