# How display footnotes in the same line, when the classdocument is beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, footmisc

When I want to display the footnotes in the same line, at the end of my first slide; The footnotes are not displayed.

I have include de option [para] in the package footmisc, this is suppose to make shown my footnotes in the same line. But rather, this option has made disappear the footnotes. Although the littler numbers are shown the final footnote is not.

This is the code I am using

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}       % or try default, Darmstadt, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}    % or try default, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%para pies de pagina horizontales
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Justificación}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Definición:} Desarrollo sostenible(DS). Preservación del equilibrio.\footnote{\cite{key}}
\item  \textbf{Enfoques}: Sostenibilidad débil: crecimiento de la riqueza; Sostenibilidad fuerte: Persistencia e integridad de los recursos, resiliencia y estabilidad de las relaciones.\footnote{\cite{key}}
\item \textbf{Problema}:
Estudio y comprensión de los sistemas desde el desarrollo sostenible: ¡Problema mundial!
\item \textbf{Modelos matemáticos}: Pueden ser usados como herramienta de decisión, diseñar estrategias, soluciones responsables
\footnote{\cite{key}, \cite{key} \cite{key}\cite{key}}.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69299/2388

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444383/getting-footcite-citations-to-display-on-the-same-line-in-beamer-slide

Comment: Great! I do really like the answer given by @samcarter. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz I did not give any answer :) I marked it as duplicate of both answers, because the technique in both answers is really the same.

Comment: This has happened before to me. I consider that this question could help a lot to other people because the title of my question is very clear and concise. When other people search for the same issue will possible find the answer even faster

Comment: @JuanMuñoz That's exactly the key point why having duplicates is a very good thing. Future users who search for the same problem will have a much better chance to find either your or one of the other questions and can follow the link to the solution.

Comment: @samcarter ¡Great!, I am excited to hear that.