# parnotes package with beamer class

Tags: beamer, footnotes, parnotes

How do I use the [`parnotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/parnotes) packages together with [`beamer`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)?

So far, the `\pause` command scrambles up the footnote numbering.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parnotes, scrextend}
\changefontsizes{20pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo\parnote{First note}\pause
        \item Bar\parnote{Second note}\pause
        \item Baz\parnote{Third note}
    \end{itemize}
    \vfill
    \footnoterule
    \parnotes
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: beamer heavily modifies footnotes. The safest way would be to not use any other packages which drastically alter footnotes.

Comment: You could fake inline footnotes like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444416/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69299/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This is a total botch, but it works -- thanks!
I hope someone will come up with an elegant solution, but at least I have something for now.

Comment: Summary for anyone else stumbling upon this: `parnotes` and `beamer` are incompatible.