# How to add two footnotes at one position in beamer?

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I am using beamer for a presentation and I want to use two footnotes at one place with a comma between them.

In the following there is no comma but the footnotes appear correctly (with `pdflatex`):

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Text\footnotemark[2]\footnotemark[3]  
  \footnotetext[1]{Text 1}
  \footnotetext[2]{Text 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If using [multiple-footnotes-at-one-point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28465/multiple-footnotes-at-one-point) with `\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}`, I get the comma, but the footnotes are not shown (it seems that it breaks the beamer footnote configuration [footmisc-in-beamer-citations-get-lost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69292/footmisc-in-beamer-citations-get-lost))

Does anyone have some suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I updated the code.

Comment: As you noted, `footmisc` is not working with `beamer`. As a simple workaround you could add `\textsuperscript{,}` between the footnotemarks.

Comment: ...something like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/eTcuPSVy).

Comment: Thanks @Werner and @dexteritas! Yes, I am currently  using that solution.

Comment: @dexteritas: Write up an answer, if you can.

Comment: @Werner Ok, I have now made it into an answer. I wanted to wait if someone has a maybe a solution that is less workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, footmisc is not working with beamer.

#### New Solution: redefine command `\footnotemark`

Another way would be do redefine `\footnotemark`, using [`etoolbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s list processing (inspired by [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87423/123129)).
This allows using multiple footnotes as comma separated list as parameter: `\footnotemark[1,2]`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\let\origfootnotemark\footnotemark
\renewcommand{\footnotemark}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
        \origfootnotemark%
    }{%
        \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{\textsuperscript{,}}}% Separator
        \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\nextitem\origfootnotemark[##1]}% How to process each item
        \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
        first automatic footnote\footnotemark
    \item
        another automatic footnote\footnotemark
    \item
        first footnote again\footnotemark[1]
    \item
        both footnotes\footnotemark[1,2]
    \end{itemize}
    \footnotetext[1]{Text 1}
    \footnotetext[2]{Text 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]

#### Old Solution: Simple workaround

As a simple workaround you could add `\textsuperscript{,}` between the footnotemarks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Text\footnotemark[1]\textsuperscript{,}\footnotemark[2]  
  \footnotetext[1]{Text 1}
  \footnotetext[2]{Text 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

##### Result

[image]