# ConTeXt: change footnote rule

Tags: footnotes, context

I wanted to know if how it was possible to change the length of the footnote rule (on the Wiki there is only the possibility of increasing the thickness, and if I remember correctly also the color).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the footnote line (thickness, length)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21913/how-can-i-change-the-footnote-line-thickness-length)

Comment: @TobiBS No, those answers are for LaTeX, and the question is about ConTeXt. Setting `\makeupwidth=<length>` (after `\starttext`) seems to work, but it doesn't look like a ConTeXt-y way of doing it.

Comment: Somewhere I had found the answer, but I lost the page link. Two ideas would come to me.
1) Remove the footnote rule (\setunotation[rule=off]) and put [before=custom_line].             2) Create a frame around the footnotes  text and delete "bottomframe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you can define almost anything you will ever need. Have fun!

```
\setuppapersize[A4]

\unexpanded\def\longrule{\blackrule[width=10cm,color=blue,height=1pt,depth=1pt]}
\setupnote[footnote][rule=command,rulecommand=\longrule]

\starttext

\input tufte\footnote{test}

\stoptext
```

[image: rulecommand]

Comment: Is there any difference to my answer?

Comment: @DG', well, it certainly allows for more customization out of the box.

Comment: How so? Looks identical to me. No criticism, just curiosity.

Comment: @DG', really?
[\blackrule](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/blackrule): Draws a horizontal filled box, called rule.
[\hrule](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/hrule): Place a rule as wide as the text, with a height of 0.4 point. Ends the current paragraph.
Using this command [\blackrule] is far more slower than using the TeX primitives \hrule and \vrule, but it save us some tokens. (Source: https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/blackrule)

Comment: Ah, I see. You focus on the content of the custom command (which I think is trivial and opinion based), whereas I saw the real challenge in persuading context to accept a custom macro in the first place. Fair enough

Comment: @DG', on the contrary! Rather trivial is looking up that `rulecommand` consists of a command: `rulecommand=COMMAND` as specified on page 243 of »ConTeXt Commands« to be found here: http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf. Choosing the most customizable rule or box was most of the work – at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own rule:

```
\def\myfootrule
  {\hrule width 10cm \relax \kern \strutdepth}

\setupfootnotes
  [rule=on,
   rule=command,
   rulecommand=\myfootrule]

\starttext
  Some text.\footnote{This is a footnote}
\stoptext
```

[image]