# Change font size of \Large etc.

Tags: fontsize

After gaining some insight from [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/how-does-font-size-work-in-tex), now I want to change my font size values according to my preference.

As a follow up from the linked question, how can I set

`\Large` = 13pt

`\LARGE` = 15pt ?

In the linked question it's `\Large` = 14.4pt and `\LARGE` = 17.28pt.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The size for article.cls with option 11pt are declared in `size11.clo`. You can copy the definitions and change them. E.g. the original `\Large` is setup like this:

```
\newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18}}
```

So use in your preamble (or a local sty).

```
\makeatletter %only needed in preamble
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{13pt}{18}}
\makeatother
```

The 18 is the baselineskip (in pt). Adjust it to the value you want to use.