# How does \footnotesize map to \fontsize{size}{baselineskip}

Tags: fontsize

We can change font size using `{\fontsize{size}{baselineskip} \selectfont .....}` with the `anyfontsize` package. I want to know what `size` and `baselineskip` values the following commands result in:

1. `\scriptsize`
2. `\footnotesize`

Comment: I believe the first one simply recalls the value previously set for the footnotes. For more info on default values, you could look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends on the default (or normal) font size. For example, specifying

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
```

leaves `\normalsize` at `10pt`, yielding

- `\scriptsize` as `7pt` (actually `\@viipt`) with a `\baselineskip` of `8pt` (actually `\@viiipt`); and
- `\footnotesize` as `8pt` (actually `\@viiipt`) with a `\baselineskip` of `9.5pt`.

From [`size10.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size10.clo):

```
\newcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
```

---

The setting

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
```

leaves `\normalsize` at `11pt`, yielding

- `\scriptsize` as `8pt` (actually `\@viiipt`) with a `\baselineskip` of `9.5pt`; and
- `\footnotesize` as `9pt` (actually `\@ixpt`) with a `\baselineskip` of `11pt`.

From [`size11.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size11.clo):

```
\newcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9.5}}
```

---

The setting

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

leaves `\normalsize` at `12pt`, yielding

- `\scriptsize` as `8pt` (actually `\@viiipt`) with a `\baselineskip` of `9.5pt`; and
- `\footnotesize` as `10pt` (actually `\@xpt`) with a `\baselineskip` of `12pt`.

From [`size12.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size12.clo):

```
\newcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9.5}}
```

---

Here's a summary table, capturing the `<size>` and `<baselineskip>` for the standard document classes across all the basic font settings, expanding that of [What point (pt) font size are `\Large`, etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764):

```
Command                  10pt           11pt           12pt
                    <size> <bskip> <size> <bskip> <size> <bskip>
\tiny                5        6      6       7      6       7
\scriptsize          7        8      8       9.5    8       9.5
\footnotesize        8        9.5    9      11     10      12
\small               9       11     10      12     10.95   13.6
\normalsize          10      12     10.95   13.6   12      14.5
\large               12      14     12      14     14.4    18
\Large               14.4    18     14.4    18     17.28   22
\LARGE               17.28   22     17.28   22     20.74   25
\huge                20.74   25     20.74   25     24.88   30
\Huge                24.88   30     24.88   30     24.88   30
```

---

Other classes (especially the major document classes such as KOMA and Memoir) may have different values.