# references in a smaller font

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, fontsize

How can I tell LyX to display the bibliographic references in a smaller font?

I use the standard "article" document class.

When I open the "Settings" of the bibliography, I get a dialog box where I can choose from many styles, but, most of them cause errors when I select them, so I use "plain". I haven't found a way to change the font size.

Comment: This would be as easy as putting `\small` or similar before the `\bibiliography` command. But I don't use LyX, it might have made things unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Seamus mentions in a comment, you can do this by adding a LaTeX command for changing font size, e.g. `\small` just before the bibliography. To add (La)TeX code in a LyX document, one has to write the code in a TeX code box, also known as an ERT (Evil Red Text), which is inserted by Insert --> TeX code, or the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

However (see comment from Stephen), note that as `\small` and friends are just switches, all text that follows will also have the new font size. Hence, any text that is after the bibliography will also be `\small`. To make the change local to the bibliography, write a `{` before `\small` in the ERT, and add a second ERT just after the bibliography where you write a closing brace, `}`.
This of course only necessary if you actually have anything after the bibliography.
See screenshot below.

#### Reference

- `\small` is a little bit smaller than the normal size, for a complete list of size commands, see for example [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc/24600#24600)

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be advantageous to use `\begin{small}...\end{small}` instead of just `\small`, because `\small` will print *everything* behind it in small print. If the references are not followed by anything, it does not matter, of course.

Comment: @Stephen Good point, I'll something like that in the answer.