# Headline with different fonts, and numeration

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I need to add to my work headline of the next form:
Author Name normal font, size 10 pkt
In the next line name of work, size 10 pkt, italic.
At right side page number, bold, italic, 14 pkt.
After that horizontal line.

Also I cannot find relationship between pkt from Word, and pt in Tex.

Comment: word almost certainly uses "big points" (tex `bp`), exactly 72 to the inch.  tex uses printer's points, 72.27 to the inch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)-package to typeset the page headers:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lhead{Author\\\textit{Name of Work}}
\rhead{\Large\textbf{\textit{\thepage}}}
\cfoot{}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

If you set the base size to `10pt`, `\Large` corresponds to approx. `14pt`. (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc))

In my copy of Word (Office 2011 for Mac), the font sizes are set in `pt`, too — I do not know about `pkt`, perhaps it is because of a different system language?

Comment: sorry it's on Polish.