# Get current font size as length

Tags: fontsize, lengths

I understand from [THIS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc) question that the current font size can be determined.

But how can I convert this to a length value?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newlength{\mytextsize}

   %This part fails.... 
   \makeatletter
      \setlength{\mytextsize}{\f@size pt}
   \makeatother

\begin{document}
    %do something.        
\end{document}
```

In other words, I want to use the 10pt declared in the `\documentclass{...}` elsewhere.

Comment: Is this question specific to the default document classes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you have is the right answer:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newlength{\mytextsize}
% This part fails...  [no it doesn't :-)]
\makeatletter
\show\f@size
\setlength{\mytextsize}{\f@size pt}
\makeatother
\showthe\mytextsize

\begin{document}
  % Do something.        
\end{document}
```

which produces a log of:

```
> \f@size=macro:
->10.
l.6 \show\f@size
                
? 
> 10.0pt.
l.10 \showthe\mytextsize
```

Showing your length has been set to 10pt.

However note that this saves the default text size not the name of the class option.
For `10pt` they happen to be the same but for `11pt` option the default font size is `10.95pt`.