# Changing Format of Table Entries

Tags: tables, syntax

I had attempted to shorten this table and I think I don't think I've edited it properly.  In particular I think that I've made a mistake changing everything up to the numeric entries.  Would anyone happen to know how I can fix this issue?  Apologies for what is likely a simple question.

```
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\fontsize{6}{6}\selectfont
\caption{First 50 terms of $G(n)$}\label{tab13}
\center{
\begin{tabular}{l r r r r r}
    \hline
    {}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}\\
    \cline{2-6}\cline{8-12}
    {}&1&2&3&4&5\\
    \hline
$V(n+0)$&1&1&1&2&2\\
$V(n+5)$&3&3&4&5&5\\
$V(n+10)$&5&6&6&7&8\\
$V(n+15)$&8&9&9&10&10\\
$V(n+20)$&10&11&11&12&13\\
$V(n+25)$&13&14&14&15&15\\
$V(n+30)$&16&17&17&17&18\\
$V(n+35)$&18&19&19&20&20\\
$V(n+40)$&20&21&21&22&23\\
$V(n+45)$&23&24&24&25&25\\
$V(n+50)$&26&27&27&27&28\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You've specified six columns, but there are 12 in the first line.

Comment: Well, I had started with a template that used 10 columns, and now I only need 5 entries.  However above where the entries start has not changed to reflect this, I think.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the issue you're referring to is an error saying something like `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`. This is caused by you using more columns in the `tabular` than defined in the argument to the environment.

That is, with `\begin{tabular}{l r r r r r}` you specify six columns, the first one left aligned, the last five right aligned. However, in the first line of the table, you have around 12 columns (i.e. 11 `&`, column separators), prompting the error.

So all you have to do to fix it is to change

```
{}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}&{}&{}&{}&$n$&{}&{}\\
    \cline{2-6}\cline{8-12}
```

to

```
& & & $n$ & & \\
\cline{2-6}
```

Additional notes:

- The empty groups (`{}`) in the empty table cells aren't needed, so I removed them.
- `\center` isn't a command that takes an argument, use just `\centering`, without any braces for what follows.
- I would use a `\baselineskip` (second argument of `\fontsize`) that is a little larger than the fontsize (first argument), for example `\fontsize{6}{7}`. (Actually, I wouldn't use `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` at all, but one of the standard commands for switching font size, listed in [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc))

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbtp]
\fontsize{6}{7}\selectfont
\caption{First 50 terms of $G(n)$}\label{tab13}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l r r r r r}
    \hline
    & & & $n$ & & \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
$V(n+0)$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
$V(n+5)$ & 3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5 \\
$V(n+10)$ & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
$V(n+15)$ & 8 & 9 & 9 & 10 & 10 \\
$V(n+20)$ & 10 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 13\\
$V(n+25)$ & 13 & 14 & 14 & 15 & 15\\
$V(n+30)$ & 16 & 17 & 17 & 17 & 18\\
$V(n+35)$ & 18 & 19 & 19 & 20 & 20\\
$V(n+40)$ & 20 & 21 & 21 & 22 & 23\\
$V(n+45)$ & 23 & 24 & 24 & 25 & 25\\
$V(n+50)$ & 26 & 27 & 27 & 27 & 28\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```