# Problems with labels inside a floating with a table

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, lyx, labels

I have this strange problem with the labels inside the floating that contains a table.
For my first table I put the label inside the floating area, then I added the cross reference  somewhere in the text. The problem is that when I created the pdf this cross reference showed number 2, when the table is the number 1.
But something even more strange happen later, It didn't matter if I had created different labels for different tables, all the cross references in the pdf showed number 2 and not the correct value according with table referenced

```
 % Vista preliminar del código fuente

%% LyX 2.0.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}


\section{\noindent evolution}

\begin{onehalfspace}
\noindent {\large This is summarized in the Table \ref{Laws}.}{\large \par}

\noindent {\large }
\begin{table}[h]
{\large }%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{0.04\textwidth}|>{\centering}p{0.05\textwidth}|}
\hline 
\multirow{1}{0.04\textwidth}{\textbf{No. }} & \textbf{Year}\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & 1974\tabularnewline
\hline 
II & 1974\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}{\large                                            }{\large \par}

{\large \caption{Law of evolution}
}{\large \par}

\label{Laws}
\end{table}
{\large \par}
\end{onehalfspace}

\begin{onehalfspace}

\subsection{\noindent The study }
\end{onehalfspace}

\begin{onehalfspace}
\noindent {\large Table \ref{paul} summarized the hypothesis.}{\large \par}

\noindent {\large }
\begin{table}[h]
{\large }%
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\raggedright}m{0.35\textwidth}|}
\hline 
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{Hypothesis}\tabularnewline
\hline 
1 & Open \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}{\large \par}

{\large \caption{Hypothesis}
}{\large \par}

\label{paul}
\end{table}
{\large \par}
\end{onehalfspace}

{\large See Table \ref{summary}.}{\large \par}

{\large }
\begin{table}[h]
{\large }%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
\textbf{\small Law} & \textbf{\small Name}\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & Continuing change\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}{\large \par}

{\large \caption{Summary}
}{\large \par}

\label{summary}
\end{table}
{\large \par}


\subsection{Status.}

{\large Look table \ref{H}.}{\large \par}

{\large }
\begin{table}[h]
{\large }%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{0.13\textwidth}|>{\raggedright}p{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline 
\textbf{Validated laws} & \textbf{Invalidated laws}\tabularnewline
\hline 
I, VI & II, III, IV, V\tabularnewline
\hline 
I, VI & II, III, IV, V\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}{\large \par}

{\large \caption{Studies}
}{\large \par}

{\large \label{H}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

With this I got these results:
For table 1 the cross references indicated number 2
For table 2 the cross references indicated number 2
For table 3 the cross references indicated number 2
For table 4 the cross references indicated number 2.2

Where did I make a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: You have to add the label either inside or after the caption, did you do that? If the label is placed before the caption it picks up the wrong number.

Comment: I have put and image to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Can you trim the document down to the minimum showing the problem, and edit the question to include the exported LaTeX source code?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Watching the code the only difference that I can see respect to one file that works is that at the end of the cross reference in the document appears this {\large \par}: See Table}
\ref{chain} (in the good one) and See Table \ref{Fernandez}.}{\large \par} (in the wrong one). Can be that?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but can you add the complete code to your question?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Not the complete project but a reduced version where I found some problems.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks a lot for the answer. I was comparing some codes when I realized this thing of the braces. But I don't know how to cancel them. And the only moment that I remember that could provoke this was when I increased the font size in the documents. I would keep trying to find the solution and I will post it. Thanks again.

Comment: If you can explain just how you increased the font size, that would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when you do

```
{\large \caption{Law of software evolution }
}
\label{Laws}
```

the pair of braces around the caption 'hides' the caption number from the label, so that it refers to something else, in this case the previous section. I don't know exactly how you did that in LyX, but if you can change it to

```
\caption{Law of software evolution }
\label{Laws}
```

it should work fine.

#### An unrelated comment, based on guesswork

From the code it looks like you've been trying to make the font size for the entire document larger by adding `\large` everywhere, and this is a rather bad idea. The default base font size is 10pt, if you go to Document --> Settings --> Fonts you can set the **Base size** to 11pt or 12pt, which will increase the size of all the text in your document.

If larger sizes are required, change the document class to *article (more font sizes)*, which gives you more options for the base size.

Comment: A very minor point: If the document's basic font size is `10pt`, then `\large` switches to `11pt`, not `12pt`. Were you maybe thinking of `\Large`?

Comment: @Mico I wasn't really thinking of what exact size `\large` refers to at all ... I'll change the text a bit.

Comment: @Mico I think you're wrong however, according to `texdoc latex2e` and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/586 `\large` is 12pt when the base size is 10pt.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected! The mistake arose because for the case of an `11pt` base size (which is what I work with for my own work...), `\large` indeed bumps up the font size by only 10%, from 10.95 to 12. However, for base sizes of `10pt` and `12pt`, the relative increase from `\large` is definitely 20%! Clearly, I shouldn't have extrapolated from the `11pt` case to the `10pt` case...