# Latex fonts causing "Undefined control sequence" error in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, lyx

I am trying to modify the font size of some text labels in a pgfplot graph I'm playing around with, but it seems pgfplot doesn't understand certain font sizes such as \normal etc. Yet the pgfplot documentation states

> A font can be any LATEX argument like \footnotesize or \small \bfseries

I have created a test-case:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
log ticks with fixed point,
xlabel=x,
ylabel=y,
enlargelimits=0.2
] 

\addplot[only marks, black, mark=triangle*, mark options={fill=white}]
coordinates { 
(0.5, 10)  
(0.6, 20)  
(0.7, 30)
}; 

\node [above] at (axis cs:  0.5,  10) {\small A}; 
\node [above] at (axis cs:  0.6,  20) {\small B}; 
\node [above] at (axis cs: 0.7, 30) {\small B};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am using LyX as my editor. The following font-sizes throw up an Undefined control sequence error:

```
\smallest 
\smaller 
\normal 
\larger 
\largest
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: None of those commands is defined.

Comment: As egreg says, you've missed which commands like that are defined. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/586 for a complete list (for the standard document classes, other classes may define other commands as well).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the commands

```
\smallest 
\smaller 
\normal 
\larger 
\largest
```

is defined in standard LaTeX. The size changing commands are (from the smalles to the largest)

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

The package `relsize` adds a facility for choosing a font by specifying how many steps from the current size, with `\larger` and `\smaller`. Similar commands are defined in the AMS classes (`amsart` and `amsbook`).