# Custom Date on Latex

Tags: formatting, datetime

I have the following code:

```
\shortdayofweekname{<day>}{<month>}{<year>}.
```

Packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}  
\newtheorem{lma}{Lemma}  
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}  
 \newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}  
\theoremstyle{definition}  
 \newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
```

I want to customize the date on my paper so that it only says "May 2014" with custom size. How can I do this? I don't have any special packages imported. I'm also using writeLatex. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the Minimum (Non)Working Example so that helpers will try to help you without any guessing on what your code is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I just started using LaTeX today. I don't know what I can show aside from what I grab off the web. I have no MWE as I don't know what to code up for the date.

Comment: Where should that short date appear? What do you mean by 'custom size'? How could/should others help without starting point? ;-)

Comment: Please take look on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure

Comment: If you're using some template, then it would probably suffice to use `\date{May 2014}`.

Comment: @Werner Wow that was fairly simple! Is it possible to change the size of the font to something bigger?

Comment: @user65422: Perhaps; try `\date{{\LARGE May 2014}}`... pick your poison, see [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) Give some feedback, and I could write an answer.

Comment: @Werner \Large was something that I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `isodate` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{isodate}

\title{Your Paper}    
\author{You}    
\date{\printdayoff\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle  

\end{document}
```

Printing the day is switched off using `\printdayoff`

If you want to change the font size use something like:

```
\date{\Huge\printdayoff\today}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following commands to customize your date:

```
day: \the\day
month: \the\month
year: \the\year
```

If you want the month displayed as a word instead of the number, you can use the datetime package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

%...

\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\shortmonthname[\the\month]  \the\year}

\begin{document}

\mydate\today

\end{document}
```

You can make it fat or change the fontsize by adding the commands in \newdateformat

```
\newdateformat{mydate}{\Huge\textbf{\shortmonthname[\the\month]  \the\year}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most document classes ([`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) included) provide the `\date{<date>}` macro which sole purpose is to store `<date>` in another macro called `\@date`. The latter is used when the title is made.

While one might think a date is required with `\date{<date>}` you can include almost *anything*. As such, a simple solution is just to supply the formatting and date style you want:

```
\date{{\Large May 2014}}
```

The internal bracing makes sure that the `\Large` scope is limited only to the use of `\@date` (wherever that may be). Typically one would require a `\par` as well to enforce the `\Large` fontsize baseline skip to be properly set. However, in a title, such specifics are rarely needed and most likely overridden by other vertical spacing.

Comment: Upvote for solution which does not require additional package.