# Edit \today in such a way that it displays 1st/2nd/3rd/4th, etc. Month Year

Tags: formatting, superscripts, environment-variables, date, variable

I have found questions [where `\today` has been edited](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180238/custom-date-on-latex) – but in such a way which I do not want to have. Yet, I do not know how to programme it.

If I write `\today`, I do not want to see something like this:

> December 2, 2017

I would like to see something like this:

> 2<sup>nd</sup> December 2017

Note that this date format should be able to distinguish between 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>, etc.

[The package `nth` with `\nth{}` might be useful.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4119/149141)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) and [`datetime2-english`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image: 2nd December 2017]

Comment: Is there a french version like fr-FR somewhere? With overleaf.com, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @pzorba75 The French version is provided with [`datetime2-french`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-french). I think there's just the regionless `french` support with that.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example, how to format the date according your needs. This snippet is adapted from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112935/82266).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}

\newdateformat{mydate}{\twodigit{\THEDAY}{ }[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\today
\mydate

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following does what you want

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[super]{nth}

\month=2
\def\today{%
  \nth{\day}
  \ifcase\month
    \or January%
    \or February%
    \or March%
    \or April%
    \or May%
    \or June%
    \or July%
    \or August%
    \or September%
    \or October%
    \or November%
    \or December\fi
    \space
    \number \year
}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image]