# How to set the listings font for the whole document

Tags: listings, lyx, fontsize

How do I change the listing font size of the whole document? 
I am quite sure that it must be specified in `Document->Settings->Listings` but I do not know the input parameter for setting the font at “smallest” size.

Thanks for your attention
Simone

Answer (score 8):

Under Document > Settings... > Listings you have to set a value for the `basicstyle` "listing parameter". Try, for example, to enter `basicstyle={\ttfamily\small}`:

[image]

This will set it in TypeWriter font and size `\small`. You can change `\small` to whatever you like, taking from (say) [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) You could also manually adjust the font size permitted that you have a scalable font selection.

Comment: Hmm... `\smallest` seems like not available. Why can I set it with the GUI but not by textual option?

Comment: OK, figured. One can activate the `View > View Source` and spy what is the TeX behind LyX formatting.