# Font sizes for different header levels

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

What are the font sizes for

- `\chapter`
- `\section`
- `\subsection`
- `\subsubsection`
- and paragraphs

when using the `report,11pt` document class? Also, what is the padding before and after each header level. I want to write a css file that to some extent emulates LaTeX look and feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, under an `11pt` document class option, you need to know the different font sizes associated with the font switching commands. Either examine [`size11.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size11.clo), or see [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

The rest can be taken directly from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

- `\chapter`; examine `\@makechapterhead` (or the starred equivalent `\@makeschapterhead`):

  - Space before: 50pt to **Chapter X**; 20pt between **Chapter X** and title
  - Font: `\huge\bfseries` = **20.74pt**
  - Space after: 40pt
- `\section`; examine the parameters passed to `\@startsection`:

  - Space before: 3.5ex ~ 16.5pt
  - Font: `\Large\bfseries` = **14.4pt**
  - Space after: 2.3ex ~ 10.8pt
- `\subsection`; examine the parameters passed to `\@startsection`:

  - Space before: 3.25ex ~ 15.3pt
  - Font: `\large\bfseries` = **12pt**
  - Space after: 1.5ex ~ 7.1pt
- `\subsubsection`; examine the parameters passed to `\@startsection`:

  - Space before: 3.25ex ~ 15.3pt
  - Font: `\normalsize\bfseries` = **11pt**
  - Space after: 1.5ex ` 7.1pt
- Regular paragraph

  - Space before: `\parskip` = 0pt
  - Font: `\normalsize` = **11pt**
  - Space after: `\parskip` = 0pt

LaTeX does provide `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` headings, but they are rarely used.

Note that LaTeX's headings have some rubber lengths built in, meaning the length may vary slightly, depending on the actual page content. However, this is of no concern for websites.