# How can i set the fontsize of different document elements?

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

I am using `\documentclass{article}` to write an article but I should change its default font size to other standards. How can I change the font size of each title or body underneath of each title? How about some words in the document?

How can I understand that each of commands `\small`, `\Huge`, etc is equivalent of what font size?

This what I want to have: I have written the font size in front of each section, also I want to left justify the abstract section.

[image]

Comment: `article` knows options `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. This changes all elements controlled by a font-size switch (headers, footnote ...). You can find the actual pointsize in `size10.clo` (substitute the 0 with 1 or 2 for 11pt or 12pt respectively).

Comment: If the fontsize should be changed, a `\fontsize{newsize}{baselineskipfaktor}\selectfont` could be used

Comment: @ChristianHupfer would it change the font of all parts? I want to change them separately since they have different font sizes

Comment: @user3482383: It will change the font size until the next change occurs, unless applied in TeX group. You should provide an example of your request, in order to make better suggestions

Comment: I added an answer for the general aspects of your question. Do you have also an example that you want to work out?

Comment: @Ruben I have add a picture of what I am going to have

Comment: Can we change the title to something like »How can i set the fontsize of different document elements?«

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, I'll do that

Answer (score 3):

The fontsize commands of LaTeX, e.g. `\small`, `\large`, etc. work in relation to the global fontsize of the document. Hence, they change if the font size of the document changes. For a detailed overview see

[What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc)

In concrete they are used like a switch. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%Some normal sized text, no changes
\lipsum[1]

%smaller text from here
\small
\lipsum[2]

%again normal sized
\normalsize
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

You can of course limit the effect of those macros to a group, i.e. `{\small This text is small\par}`. In this case text that follows the group won't be affected. (Note the `\par` concluding the group to apply the correct line spacing.)

Now, you can change the font size of the document globally by declaring the `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` option while calling the documentclass as:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
```

Regarding your example I used the `titlesec` package to patch the sectional headings. The customization of the title and the abstract - note that I added a `\keywords` macro - is hand-crafted. A complete code could be:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}
\usepackage{textcase,url,titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\relax}
            {\large\BoldAllcaps{\thesection}}{1em}{\large\BoldAllcaps}

\newcommand{\BoldAllcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\scshape\bfseries #1}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\Large\bfseries \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\small \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}%
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\section*{\abstractname}}{\relax}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\vspace{.5em}\noindent{\large\bfseries \keywordsname:} #1\par}
  \def\keywordsname{Keywords}
\makeatletter

\title{Title of paper}
\author{Author}
\date{Affiliation, \url{e@ma.il}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
  \keywords{blah, blah}
\end{abstract}

\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: fontsize_ex]