# To define smaller fontsize for part and section

Tags: fontsize

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\part{1. At the next lecture we will be talking about binary mixtures and their phase behaviour.}
\section{The system consists of two types of particles (say, A and B)}

\section{The particles fill a simple 3D lattice}

\end{document}
```

where I write my answers between. 
However, actually the first sentence in Part is longer. 
It looks massive:

[image]

**How can you make the font smaller for part and section?**

I can apply this

```
{\fontsize{0.3cm}{0.4em}\selectfont \textbf{This is small but bold!}}
```

to one sentence but the challenge is to apply it to some declaration that defines the size of the font in part and sections.

Comment: which document class do you use?

Comment: My document class is article.

Comment: +1 for the `sectsty` answer. If you only need to adjust the font size or style of the headings and nothing more fancy, it is much simpler to use `sectsty` than `titlesec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy with the `sectsty` package.

Just define

```
\parttitlefont{\Large}
\sectionfont{\large}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\parttitlefont{\Large}
\sectionfont{\large}

\begin{document}

\part{1. At the next lecture we will be talking about binary mixtures and their phase behaviour.}

\section{The system consists of two types of particles (say, A and B)}

\section{The particles fill a simple 3D lattice}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: \Large is still too large. I changed \Large to \large and \large to \small which seem to be ok size. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It is strange that they have not documented the variety of different fontsize here in the manual of sectsty: http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/sectsty.pdf Do you know where they do classification of fontsize parameters?

Comment: @Masi you can find them in every LaTeX book, but you can simply have a look at this answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/27635

Answer (score 1):

You can use the titlesec package. It allows many modifications of that kind. You may want to look into its documentation for details, but for a part-heading that is only slightly larger than the section heading you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\LARGE\bfseries}{Part~\thepart}{8pt}{}

\begin{document}

\part{1. At the next lecture we will be talking about binary mixtures and their phase behaviour.}
\section{The system consists of two types of particles (say, A and B)}

\section{The particles fill a simple 3D lattice}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility. Copy commands for `part` and `section` definitions from `article.cls` into your preamble and change fontsize commands according your taste. Be careful, if you change only `part` and `section` all other titles (subsection, paragraph) won't change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
       \large\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par\nobreak
     \fi
     \Large \bfseries #2%
     \markboth{}{}\par}%
    \nobreak
    \vskip 3ex
    \@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{1. At the next lecture we will be talking about binary mixtures and their phase behaviour.}
\section{The system consists of two types of particles (say, A and B)}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The particles fill a simple 3D lattice}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]