# determine the exact size and position of titles with the titlesec package

Tags: titlesec

I need 11pt titles and don't know what to do, 'medium' seems quite vague.
This is my code:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Medium\upfamily\centering}
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\Medium}
```

Comment: Where did you find this `\Medium` command? Sma question for the `\upfamily`. I suppose you mean `\upshape`

Comment: in the titlesec package pdf.

Comment: Oh! I see. They aren't commands, They're keywords used as options for the simple use of the package. The `titleformat`is one of the `advanced commands. Are you sure you want a `11pt` size for chapter tiles? It's a size for normal text.

Answer (score 2):

The `medium` in `titlesec` is a package option, not a command. So it is accessed by `\usepackage[medium]{titlesec}`.  If you need *all* section titles to be 11pt, and your document text is also 11pt, the use `\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}` which makes all headings (except chapters) to be the text font size.

To make chapter headings the same size as the main document font size, you can use `\normalfont` in the chapter title definition.

Here's a small document that shows both patterns.  I've added the `\fontsize` macro from [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/2693) to show the actual size.

The `tiny` option sets all section and lower headings to the same size as the font size.  It doesn't change chapter headings and you say you want them centred so I have given an example of how to do that.

To adjust the chapter spacing you need to supply values for the `\titlespacing` command.  To set the titles immediately above the following text you can set the spacing to `0pt`. using `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
     {\normalfont\bfseries\fillast}
     {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
     {0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{\thefontsize{This is a chapter }}
Some text.
\section{\thefontsize{This is a section}}
\subsection{\thefontsize{This is a subsection}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Related: [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Comment: @Werner Actually that might confuse the issue, because the `titlesec` use of these terms as package options doesn't match their use as fontsize commands.

Comment: For package options, true. For setting the font size manually, it depends on the default document font size and then the macros make sense.

Comment: Many thanks. Now, what about positioning chapter titles 12pts above the main text?

Comment: @GuillaumeCoatalen I've updated my answer.