# Minor difference in width of column and text

Tags: width

Below is an MWE.

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape}{}{0pt}{\colorsection}{}
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{\colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\thesection \centering #1}}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\vspace{-15mm}\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont\textbf{A Minimum Working Example}} % Article title
\author{}
\date{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Insert title

\thispagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{2} % Two-column layout throughout the main article text

\section*{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3] % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section*{Discussion}

\lipsum[7] % Dummy text

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

As you can see that there is a minor difference in width of the column and the width of the column text itself. How can I correct the discrepancy?

[image]

Comment: Your title font choice doesn't work here - there is no `24pt` font. Use something like `\LARGE` or `\huge`, or `\Huge`, depending on what's closest. See [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764) for a discussion on font sizes that are based on your default document class choice (10pt in your case).

Comment: @Werner: Why shouldn't the code `\fontsize{24pt}{10pt}\selectfont` work ? I guess the O.P. uses vector fonts, as every one does nowadays.

Comment: @Bernard: The font is only available in certain sizes. You'll receive a LaTeX font warning "Size substitutions with differences up to 0.88pt have occurred." as the CM font is only available in 24.88pt, not 24pt.

Comment: Even the opentype versions? And how does the lettrine package to scale fonts in an exact way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `\colorbox`es necessarily add a gap between the contents and the outer edge of the box. This width is called `\fboxsep`, since a `\colorbox` is an `\fbox` without any rules around it. As such, use

```
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
  \colorbox{blue!20}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep]{#1}}}
```

for your `\colorsection`:

[image]

I've used `\makebox[<width>]{<stuff>}` instead of a `\parbox`, as the latter is not needed here. `\makebox` necessarily centres its contents.

Since `\thesection` is technically a no-op, I've removed it from the heading setting as well.