# LyX Enumerate how to size item number

Tags: lyx, fontsize, enumerate

When I go into the Enumerate environment in LyX, it generates item numbers, but they are much larger than I would like.  Is there a way to specify the size of the item numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label={\small\arabic*.}}
```

The above will set the `1`st level of the `enumerate` environment to print the `label` in `\small` font. You can [change `\small` to something else](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764), depending on the size you're after.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code into my LaTex preamble, but it had no effect.   When I tried to put my doc into PDF I got a whole bunch of errors: "package fontec Error: Encoding file 'lgrenc.def' not found"  "LaTex Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly"; "corrupted NFSS tables".  I'm a beginner at this, and really do not know what to do.

Comment: I took all that code out of my preamble, but I am still getting the same errors and cannot convert to pdf.

Comment: @BettyMock: Are you running MiKTeX or TeX Live with your LyX?

Comment: I don't know.  I just installed the Ubuntu version from the software center, whatever that involves.  I have determined that the problem is not in the preamble but in the enumerate environment itself.  If I use it, I get those errors.  How do I check whether I am running either of those packages?

Comment: Well, it isn't the enumerate environment either.  It was choking on a special symbol I brought in from Word.  thanks for your help.