# How to generate a smaller \sim with respect to text

Tags: symbols, fontsize, relation-symbols

When I use `\sim` I get:

[image]

Is there a way to make the `\sim` sign smaller with respect to the text?

I looked online but did not find what I was looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example we can copy-paste-compilet to see what you see. This is obviously highly font dependent and the image you've posted doesn't seem to be CMR.

Comment: I would support @cfr 's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\mathpalette` trickery we can choose the smaller size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\smallsim}{\smallsym{\mathrel}{\sim}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallsym}[2]{#1{\mathpalette\make@small@sym{#2}}}
\newcommand{\make@small@sym}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th\downgrade@style#1#2$}}%
}
\newcommand{\downgrade@style}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
      \scriptscriptstyle
  \fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

exchange $\sim 60\%$ and $\sim 15\%$

exchange $\smallsim 60\%$ and $\smallsim 15\%$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I defined a generic `\smallsym` command in case you need other symbols to be made smaller in a similar way. For instance, with

```
\newcommand{\smallcirc}{\smallsym{\mathbin}{\circ}}
```

you get

[image]

from the input

```
$f\circ g$

$f\smallcirc g$
```

Comment: Small doubt: since using `\m@th` is a good practice, why is it so commonly used at the begining of math mode `$\m@th#1#2$` rather than at the end `$#1#2\m@th$`?

Comment: @Manuel Tradition? The chances `#2` sets `\mathsurround` are very small.

Comment: I was asking in case there was something more to that decision.  In any case, since it's so simple, I don't see why tradition has taken us to a different path.

Comment: shouldn't the (small) `\sim` be unary?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think so; but of course it's possible to make it a unary symbol by doing `${\smallsim}60\%$`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `{\small \sim}`, `{\scriptsize \sim}` or `{\footnotesize \sim}` for example. See e. g. [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599) for more font size related commands.