# How to automatically adjust font size for listings, so it fits gives amount of textwidth?

Tags: fonts, formatting, listings

For code listings, I often change the `listings` parameter `basicstyle` to adjust the font size so that listing fit within the container it is in.

I mainly use a cell in a table to display small listing in. But the container could be a `minipage` or the whole page, or anything else.

So in a table cell, I use `\linewidth` or it could be some percentage of the `textwidth`.

I also know the number of characters of the widest (longest) line of the listing. I wrote a small lua function which finds this value.

I just do not know how to use the above 2 pieces of information, in order to map it to the correct font size to tell `listing` to use such that it fits.

Assuming for now that `11pt` class is used. But it will be nice if this would work for arbitrary value and also any font family that happens to be used.

Here is a MWE showing an example listing, which I want to show in a table. I know the space needed, which is `\linewidth`, and I calculate that the longest line is `56` characters for this example, and I know I am using 11 pt.

What should the font size be then so that the listing would fit in? For example, when using `\small` it does not fit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code for the above is (MWE)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function getMaxLineWidth()
local maxLineLength = 0;

   local r    
   for line in io.lines("code.m") do
       r = string.len(line)
       print(line,r)
       if r>maxLineLength then
          maxLineLength=r
       end
   end     
   tex.print(maxLineLength)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\getMaxLineWidth}{\directlua{ getMaxLineWidth() }}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatimwrite}{code.m} 
clear all; 
syms s t
f = (s^4+5*s^3+6*s^2+9*s+30)/(s^4+6*s^3+21*s^2+46*s+30);
pretty(f)
\end{verbatimwrite}

\begin{tabular}{|p{0.7\textwidth}|}\hline    
space available for the listing is     \the\linewidth and the 
The maximum line width is \getMaxLineWidth \ then
what should be the font size below so it will fit?

\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,backgroundcolor=\color{bg},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]{code.m}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

By trial and error `scriptsize` is found to work:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this manual adjustment is what I am trying to avoid. I think knowing the space available in `pt` and knowing the number of characters, and also the font size used for the document, it should be possible to calculate what font size is needed to pass to the `listing` command so this is all automated?

I am also not sure if one can specify an arbitrary font size value, or is one limited to the values given by `\normalsize,\small`, etc... ?

Can this be automated?

For reference, thanks for answer [what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Suppose you have an extremely long line by accident and the calculation you are asking for returns `\fontsize{0.6pt}{.07pt}\selectfont` ... Do you think the result will be useful? ;-)

Comment: That's what `breaklines` of `listings` and `minted` is for ... Additional to the example of Johannes_B: Imagine that you have many listings with different line lengths. This would result in many different font sizes for your listings. And that is what I would call _bad typography_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for this comes from [David Carlisle in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30649368#30649368). Basically, you put the listing in a box that will be scaled down if wider than some width. The `adjustbox` package provides an easy interface for doing just this.

Note however, as [Ulrike Fischer mentions in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30649848#30649848), that this may well end up looking horrible (such as my example below), but if looks are irrelevant, then by all means.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{style=Matlab-editor,breaklines=false}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
x = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m +n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + x + y
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
x = a + b + c + d + e + f
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i'd recommend always using `\small` for listing material to try to cut down on the number of instances that need to be adjusted; this will make the output appear much more uniform than it would if a majority of instances are adjusted.  unless the main text is already very small, the smaller listing inserts make them easily recognizable, and not that hard to read with a monospace font.