# How do I bold just the numbering in the exam class?

Tags: numbering, fontsize, exam

I am using the exam class, how do I bold the numbering?

And one more question, how do I change the font size to 14 pt or 16 pt in the exam class?

Comment: welcome  to TeX.se.  First question  is unclear for second  try `\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}` or `\usepackage[17pt]{extsizes}`

Comment: for the numbering of questions, you might be interested in the macro `\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\arabic{question}}`

Comment: Thanks for the numbering tip. But how do I change the . to )? and how do I make more white space between the numbering and the paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

A table of standard LaTeX font sizes can be [found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc), using `\large` or `\Large`. If you want specific sizes by point (.e.g., 14 pt) try the package suggested in the comments to your question.

For the spacing question you pose in the comments, you should ask a separate question providing more detail about what you are looking for. You should also include a minimum working example that shows what you have tried so far. Otherwise, you are unlikely to get a response.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion)} %replace period with parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\large\arabic{question}}

\begin{document}

\question
Here is the first question.


\question
Here is the second question.

\end{document}
```

[image]