# Package caption Error: 9pt undefined

Tags: captions, fontsize

How to set the font size for captions using specific sizes (e.g.: 9pt)?

I've been trying to set the captions to 9pt using the following command:

```
\usepackage[font={9pt,bf}]{caption}
```

But it fails. The error message is `Package caption Error: 9pt undefined`.

On the other hand, using `footnotesize` (or any other) works ok.

Comment: use `\usepackage[font={small,bf}]{caption}`

Comment: does small enforce an specific size?

Comment: yes, but it depends to your main font size

Comment: @rkioji: `small` depends on your default document font setting. See what `\small` looks like relative to what you have in `\documentclass[.]{..}`: [What point (`pt`) font size are `\Large` etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`caption` knows only a specific set of font keywords. If you want something special you must setup the keyword first:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{9pt}{\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font={9pt,bf}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 blblblblb
\caption{blblb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]