# IEEE conference title font size

Tags: titles, fontsize, ieeetran

I have downloaded the [IEEE template for the conference](https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) - using `bare_conf.tex`.

My supervisor thinks that the font size of the title is big. So how can I change the title font size?

Answer (score 5):

The default title is set using `\Huge` and the easiest way to change this would be to issue the updated font size within the title. That is (say)

```
\title{\large Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls \\ for IEEE Conferences}
```

[image]

For other font size switches and their respective point sizes, see [What point (pt) font size are `\Large` etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/5764)