# Correct approach to 10pt quote size?

Tags: fontsize, quoting

Some specification for thesis require 10pt quote on a separate line. Assuming that the thesis is written with 12pt is this correct approach to obtain 10pt for quote?

Is any other simple solution?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{quote}
\footnotesize{\kant[1]}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/134144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked,

> Assuming that the thesis is written with `12pt` is [`\footnotesize` the] correct approach to obtain `10pt` for quote?

Short answer: Yes. More precisely, it's *one among several* possible correct approaches to obtaining the desired formatting outcome.

Now on to a longer answer. The `report` document class defines the option `12pt` as follows:

```
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
```

whereby `\@ptsize` is set to `2`. Later on in `report.cls`, one finds these instructions:

```
\ProcessOptions
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}
```

This (a) executes `\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}` and (b) inputs the file `size12.clo` as `\@ptsize` is expanded to `2`.

Next, in the file `size12.clo`, one finds the following instructions:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}%
   % (other stuff)
   }
```

and

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt
   % (other stuff)
   }
```

Aside: `\@xpt` and `\@xiipt` expand to `10` and `12`, respectively.

Long story short: If the `report` class is loaded with the option `12pt`, the main font size -- `\normalsize` -- is 12pt on 2.5 points of leading, while `\footnotesize` works out to 10pt on 2 points of leading. ("Leading" is an old-fashioned (archaic??) expression, which refers to the thickness of the strips of lead that were inserted between lines of metal type.)

What to do with all this information?

- If your document has just one `quote` environment, it's perfectly alright to insert the instruction `\footnotesize` right after `\begin{quote}`.

  Aside: Note that `\footnotesize` is a *switch* and doesn't take an argument. Thus, `\footnotesize{\kant[1]}` is no different from `\footnotesize \kant[1]`; the latter is preferable since it doesn't create any false impressions.
- If your document features several `quote` environments and if they must all be typeset at 10pt, I suggest you load the `etoolbox` package in the preamble and insert the instruction

  ```
  \AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\footnotesize}
  ```

  to automate the process of switching to the required font size.
- If, for some reason, you take pride in making LaTeX execute only the absolutely minimal number of instructions needed to get a given job done, you might observe that `\footnotesize` actually performs additional instructions -- such as changing the default amount of vertical whitespace that's inserted above and below displayed equations -- besides changing the font size to 10pt on 2pt of leading; it turns out that these additional instructions aren't needed here. Indeed, instead of running `\footnotesize`, you could also run

  ```
  \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont
  ```

  to get the desired font size.

Comment: Excellent explanation for my problem. I will bookmark this answer for future references. For the moment I'll use your solution with `etoolbok` which is preferable of `\newcommand` which crossed my mind.