# How to set fontsize of 14pt in article class

Tags: fontsize, article, class-options

I would like to set the fontsize of `14pt` in the `article` class.  But, using [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/4301), I obtain:

[image]

#### Questions:

1. I am assuming that the output means that the closest font size available is `14.4pt`.  Why did the font size not default to `12pt` or `14.4pt` instead of `10pt`?
2. How do I set the font size to `14.4pt`.  Using `\documentclass[14.4pt]{article}` yields identical output as above.

#### References:

- [What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/4301)

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}

\makeatletter
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24599/4301
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\sffamily
%\thefontsize\tiny
%\thefontsize\scriptsize
%\thefontsize\footnotesize
%\thefontsize\small
\thefontsize\normalsize
\thefontsize\large
\thefontsize\Large
\thefontsize\LARGE
\thefontsize\huge
\thefontsize\Huge
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `extsizes` package makes it possible to have a 14pt base font size, with `\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `article` document class with a basic font size of `14pt` (14.4pt for sticklers for detail), you should run

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
```

There's also `extreport` and `extbook`. These three document classes provide the following extra font size options (other than the usual `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`, of course): `8pt`, `9pt`, `14pt`, `17pt`, and `20pt`.

Answer (score 4):

With the `fontsize` package you can set arbitrary sizes and adjust the line spacing accordingly.

For example, you can set `\normalisze` to 14.4pt with:

```
\usepackage[fontsize=14.4]{fontsize}
```

In this case the line spacing defaults to 17.28pt (= 1.2 * 14.4).

if you want to specify the line spacing (for example 16pt) you will need this other command:

```
\changefontsize[16]{14.4}
```

Finally you can see a text sample for every available size with the following command:

```
\printsamples{⟨baselineskip⟩}{⟨fontsize⟩}[⟨sizes⟩]
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontsize}
  \changefontsize[16]{14.4}
  \sampletext{Lorem ipsum}

\begin{document}

\printsamples{16}{14.4}[footnotesize,smallr,normalsize,large,larger,largerr]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this also applicable to memoir class?

Comment: Yes, but I suppose the `memoir` class has its own commands