# I have a 12 font size in my template, but in my work I need to make a 14 font size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I have a 12pt font size in my template, but in my work I need to make a 14pt font size. When I write a command `\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}` (instead of `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}`), chapters and sub-chapters are no longer displayed in my work (2 figure).[image]

[image]

Comment: no, I have already tried this solution

Comment: Welcome - so, explain why it didn't work for you in your question...

Comment: Use the report class and the other answer on the duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637950/38080

Comment: it works, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the `report` document class, the `article` and `extarticle` document classes do not provide `\chapter`-type instructions. If your document contains `\chapter` instructions, you should be getting error and warning messages to this effect.

You shouldn't have switched from `report` to `extarticle`. Instead, you should have switched from `report` class to `extreport`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
```