# Increasing the Gap Produced by \Linebreak within a Small Caps Title

Tags: luatex, line-breaking, titles, small-caps, vertical-spacing

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large

\begin{center}
{\scshape{H O W \, T O \, I N C R E A S E \, T H E \, S P A C E\linebreak A F T E R \, T H E \, L I N E B R E A K.}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\vspace*{15pt}
\begin{center}
{\scshape{H O W \, T O \, I N C R E A S E \, T H E \, S P A C E\linebreak \vspace*{10pt} A F T E R \, T H E \, L I N E B R E A K.}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\vspace*{15pt}
\begin{center}
{\scshape{H O W \, T O \, I N C R E A S E \, T H E \, S P A C E\linebreak \\[0pt] A F T E R \, T H E \, L I N E B R E A K.}}
\end{center}
\vspace*{15pt}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

In the first title, I simply used `S P A C E\linebreak` and the result suggests that more vertical space is needed between the two title lines.

The second title was produced by using `\linebreak` followed by `\vspace*{10pt}` immediately after "S P A C E"; which alas, did not increase the vertical space between the title lines, but rather between the title and the paragraph.

The third title was produced using `\\[0pt]`, which did increase the gap between the title lines---but surprisingly so, because of the `0pt` specification. I do not understand why the vertical gap increased at all---it seems reasonable to have expected nothing.

It seems that in order to increase the default gap to something aesthetically agreeable, I would have to use a negative point value in place of `0pt`, which again, seems contrary to reason.

*Remark:* The gap produced by `\linebreak` seems to be fine when used in a paragraph with ordinary text.

QUESTION: (i) Can someone suggest the best way to either specify or increase the vertical gap between two lines in a small caps title, such as the one given in the MWE? (ii) Also, as my actual document contains a fair number of such titles all using the same font size, how may I define a command, e.g., `\linebreak1`, which when invoked, would produce a vertical gap of some specified amount in lieu of the default for `\linebreak`, which works fine within paragraphs?

The code is compiled with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a very important point here.  "Small caps" come from a "caps and small caps" font, and the small cap letters are replacements for the lowercase letters in the font.  You are entering the uppercase letters, so the distance between baselines is what is expected.

Comment: if you really want to use vspace you would need to put it before `\\ ` not after.

Comment: also, you might want to use `microtype`'s `\textls` command instead of manually spacing out the titles

Comment: @Robert Thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for posting this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
begin{center}
{\scshape{H O W \, T O \, I N C R E A S E \, T H E \, S P A C E\linebreak
A F T E R \, T H E \, L I N E B R E A K.}}
\end{center}
```

is Ok except for the two sets of spurious braces, and use of all capitals (in which case there is no reason to use `\scshape` at all as the capitals are the same as the roman font capitals). So this should be

```
\begin{center}
\scshape H o w \, T o \, I n c r e a s e \, T h e \, S p a c e\linebreak
A f t e r \, T h e \, L i n e b r e a k.
\end{center}
```

although I'd use `\\`  rather than `\linebreak`.

In the second case, `\vspace` in horizontal mode adds the space after the line so

```
\linebreak \vspace*{10pt} A F T E R
```

should be

```
\vspace*{10pt} \linebreak A F T E R
```

If you really want to use that form.

The third case,

```
\linebreak \\[0pt]
```

Is just wrong you have two adjacent forced linebreaks. use `\linebreak` or `\\`  not both.

So I would use the first form but replace `\linebreak` by `\\[whatever]` actually I think it looks better without the extra space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\large


\begin{center}
\scshape H o w \, T o \, I n c r e a s e \, T h e \, S p a c e\\ A f t e r \, T h e \, L i n e b r e a k.
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
\scshape H o w \, T o \, I n c r e a s e \, T h e \, S p a c e\\[5pt] A f t e r \, T h e \, L i n e b r e a k.
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

Comment: answer 10001 to your questions  that mentions that font switches do not take an argument.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm beginning to see too many braces can easily mess other things up. With this simple solution, I guess there's no need for a "\linebreak1" command.

Answer (score 4):

You want to act on `\baselinestretch`. In the first example, only letterspacing is applied just to ensure that the vertical spaces around the centered part is the same.

For letterspacing it's *much* better to use `microtype` facilities.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{spacedcenteredsc}
 {\par\vspace{-0.4\baselineskip}\begin{center}\linespread{1.4}\scshape\lsstyle}
 {\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{center}
\scshape\lsstyle
How To Increase The Space \\ After The Linebreak.
\end{center}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{spacedcenteredsc}
How To Increase The Space \\ After The Linebreak.
\end{spacedcenteredsc}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Note that this will scale automatically depending on the current font size.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @egreg.

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** The general method is to use `\fontsize{<size pt>}{<skip pt>}\selectfont`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   
\large  

\begin{center}
    \fontsize{14}{28}\selectfont            
    \scshape  How \, To \, Increase \, The, Space\\  After \, The \, Linebreak. 
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]\bigskip


\begin{center}
    \fontsize{18}{36}\selectfont            
    \scshape  How \, To \, Increase \, The, Space\\  After \, The \, Linebreak. 
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

**(2)** Here is command to increase the space between lines, using a fixed font size `\xlinebreak[<optional font size>]{<skip in pt>}` has 2 arguments, the first optional with a **default value** of 14pt, the second, mandatory,  the desired skip.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\xlinebreak}[2][14pt]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\selectfont} % added `\linebreak[<optional, font size>]{<skip in pt>} <<<


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   
\large  

\begin{center}
    \xlinebreak{18pt}   % font size 14 pt, skip 18 pt           
    \scshape  How \, To \, Increase \, The, Space\\  After \, The \, Linebreak. 
\end{center}
\bigskip    

\begin{center}
    \xlinebreak{28pt}   % font size 14 pt, skip 28 pt           
    \scshape  How \, To \, Increase \, The, Space\\  After \, The \, Linebreak. 
\end{center}

\bigskip    

\begin{center}
    \xlinebreak{36pt}   % font size 14 pt, skip 36 pt       
    \scshape  How \, To \, Increase \, The, Space\\  After \, The \, Linebreak. 
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\xlinebreak[18pt]{32pt} % font size 18 pt, skip 36 pt           
\scshape  How \, To \, Increase \, The, Space\\  After \, The \, Linebreak. 
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

**(3)** Run this code to print the font size of a document

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 Font size is: \f@size pt}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \sffamily
    
    \thefontsize\tiny (tiny)
    
    \thefontsize\scriptsize (scriptsize)
    
    \thefontsize\footnotesize (footnotesize)
    
    \thefontsize\small (small)
    
    \thefontsize\normalsize (normal size)
    
    \thefontsize\large (large)
    
    \thefontsize\Large (Large)
    
    \thefontsize\LARGE (LARGE)
    
    \thefontsize\huge (huge)
    
    \thefontsize\Huge (Huge)
\end{document}
```

[image: c]

Using `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`  produces a normal size of 10.95pt.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/161015

Comment: The initial font size is `\large`. Do you know, or perhaps, where I can find out, what point value `\large` (or some other font size) translates into? You have given {14} here---is that `large`? Also, is there a way perhaps, as the question asks, to define a command similar to `\linebreak`, say, `linebreak1` where a linebreak is inserted with a specified gap  such as your {28} for all such linebreaks where "`\linebreak1`" is invoked? Thank you.

Comment: `size10.clo`  `\DeclareRobustCommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14}}`  so it's 12pt on 14pt

Comment: Thank you for your answer.