# Setspace fine-tuning or an alternative for scrbook

Tags: koma-script, line-spacing, msword, setspace

I'm looking for either an option of `setspace` that is between `onehalfspacing` and `doublespacing` or an alternative to `setspace`. Unfortunately, I need to be closer to the Word's 1.5 paragraph spacing to satisfy a thesis requirement.

I'm using a KOMA-script `scrbook` class, so if there is a built-in functionality, that would be best.

`onehalfspacing` result is too narrow:

[image]

`doublespacing` is too wide:

[image]

`\setstretch{1.45}` looks about right, but I'm not sure if this is safe to use with regard to list environments and similar. The `setspace`'s documentation is quite terse.

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A look into `setspace.sty` reveals, that the three commands `\single...`, `\onehalf...` and `\doublespacing` just use a `\setstretch{...}` command, with the factor depending on documentclass' setting of fontsize, i.e. `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`. There is no further option except of `nodisplayskipstretch`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you turn this comment into an answer, so that we can resolve this question? Thank you.

Comment: The meaning of line distance in Word isn't equal to LaTeX. You have to be aware the typographical term ["leading"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading). Se: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20939/what-exactly-is-leading

Comment: @ipavlic: It was just meant as a comment, I think it is not really a solution.

Comment: For every German user: http://blog.jusmi.de/2013/03/schrift-einfach-nach-belieben-oder/

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Did you just change the link? ;-) I was confused about that `funeral sermon` on ARIAL.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A look into setspace.sty reveals, that the three commands

`\singlespacing`, 
`\onehalfspacing` and 
`\doublespacing`

just use a

`\setstretch{...}` command, with the factor depending on setting of fontsize (e.g. as optional parameter to the `\documentclass`), i.e. 10pt, 11pt, 12pt.

There is no further option except of `nodisplayskipstretch`.

Most probably one has to use `\setstretch{x}` with some experimental value `x`, found out by direct comparison on screen with MS Word and `*.tex` output **and** a printout of both documents.

It is very difficult (thanks to Marco Daniels comment above) to compare  linespacings in MS Word and `LaTeX` and perhaps in other word editors/typesetters.

Answer (score 2):

Got same issue for my thesis.
`\linespread{<factor>}` is the command to use, but for the factor value, i tried 1.5, 1.45, 1.4 and so on. An the right value is 1.43 !
Checked with a printed sample text using Word.