# How can I convert Microsoft Word format "Line Spacing | Multiple 1.15" to LaTeX document?

Tags: line-spacing

In order to achieve Microsoft Word format "Line Spacing | Multiple 1.15" in a LaTeX document, I have used the following commands:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\linespread{1.15}
```

Is that right?

Comment: No. Either it is `\onehalfspacing`, or it is `\linespread{1.15}` (does not require `\setspace`), or `\setspace{1.15}`.  `setspace` takes into account the problem of  footnotes, lists, &c. Note `\onehalfspacing` is *not* `\setstretch{1.5}`, contrary to what might naively think.

Comment: I do not know, but it could be that you are stuck in the MS word way of thinking. You are not suppose to adjust the lines space - choose a document type, and the format is already as it should be.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65849/confusion-onehalfspacing-vs-spacing-vs-word-vs-the-world and  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean are of interest.