# Changing font size and spacing on loaded document?

Tags: fonts, spacing, document-classes, resume

Probably going to be downvoted to oblivion but I'm trying to form a quick resume and need the spacing to be a bit wider/font a bit larger (I got the document from a pre-made template. The code is below.

```latex
% Quickly hacked together from .docx sample provided by Scimisc
\RequirePackage{ifpdf,ifxetex,ifluatex}
\
  \RequirePackage{cmap}
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \input{glyphtounicode}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_f}{FB00}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_i}{FB03}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_f_l}{FB04}
  \pdfglyphtounicode{f_i}{FB01}
  \pdfgentounicode=1
\fi


%  \RequirePackage{caladea}
%  \RequirePackage{carlito}
% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{needspace}
\RequirePackage[compact,small,explicit]{titlesec}

\def\scimisc@cvname{}
\def\scimisc@cvpersonalinfo{}
\def\cvinfosep{\hfill|\hfill{}}

\newcommand{\cvname}[1]{\def\scimisc@cvname{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvpersonalinfo}[1]{\def\scimisc@cvpersonalinfo{#1}}

\newcommand{\cvtitlefamily}{\rmfamily}
\newcommand{\cvnamefont}{\cvtitlefamily\huge\bfseries}
\newcommand{\cvpersonalinfofont}{\normalsize}

\newcommand{\makecvtitle}{%
  \begin{center}
      {\cvnamefont\MakeTextUppercase{\scimisc@cvname}\par}
      \vskip4pt\hrule height 0.6pt \relax
      {\cvpersonalinfofont\scimisc@cvpersonalinfo\par}
  \end{center}\medskip
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cvsubsection}{m o o o}{%
%   \vspace{\parskip}%
  \needspace{4\baselineskip}%
  \textbf{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\hfill\textbf{#2}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\IfValueT{#4}{\\}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\emph{#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{\hfill\emph{#4}}
  \par\vspace{-\parskip}
}

\geometry{a4paper,margin=0.5in}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\bfseries\rmfamily\large}{\thesection}{0pt}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}[{\titlerule[0.6pt]}]
\setlist{leftmargin=*,nosep}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

Comment: Please make this code sniplet into something others can test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help with your question.

Comment: Things to try: you can make the text large by putting `\large` just before the text for which you want to increase the font size. See also https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/ for other font size commands and different ways to set the font size. For line spacing you can take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65849/confusion-onehalfspacing-vs-spacing-vs-word-vs-the-world.