# Template Specification

Tags: templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does 'double spacing' mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean)

What does "12 point type and 1.5 or double spacing" means and how could I make sure that the template am I using [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5301947/CUEDThesisPSnPDF.zip) is complied with this requirement?

Comment: If you're really picky about "12pt", [Setting a document in MS Word-12pt (12bp)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34024) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look into file `thesis.tex` located in your given link you can see that this `thesis.tex` fullfill the requirements.

`12 pt type` means the size of your font for normal text in your document. LaTeX builds the headings with greater fonts automaticly. With "double spacing" is a special distance between two lines of text ment. Have a look to the question marked as duplicate (David Carlisle mentioned it in a noe deleted comment).