# Why the \doublespacing command in LaTeX actually produce 1.6 times spacing? (Compared to Pages '09 4.2, 12pt, Times New Roman)

Tags: line-spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ‘double spacing’ mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean)

Why the `\doublespacing` command in LaTeX actually produce 1.6 times spacing? (Compared to Pages '09 4.2, 12pt, Times New Roman)

I am writing an MLA format paper, which requires doublespace 12pt TNR layout. I am using LaTeX to produce my paper, and I find that my lines in paper are more condensed compared to other students' papers, which are typed by What-You-See-Is-What-You-Get word processors (i.e. Microsoft Word, Apple Pages, etc.) After experiments, I find that LaTeX produces approximately 1.6 times spacing, under the standard of Pages.

The command I used in LaTeX are:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Instead of using `\doublespacing`, you may have to use `\setstretch{2}`. `\doublespacing` issues `\setstretch{1.655}` under a `12pt` font. See [What does 'double spacing' mean?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13742/5764)

Comment: Double spacing is *not* a LaTeX concept; since its meaning is somewhat arbitrary, the authors of `setspace` decided for one possible sense (and they're not alone). Personally I find that double spacing should be banished altogether.

Comment: I believe that this is a duplicate of the question @Werner points out. Hopefully Luke will register here and clarify this.