# How do I ask LaTeX to exactly fill up a page?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, setspace

I understand that I can control interline spacing in LaTeX in a number of ways. The commands like [`\baselineskip`](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/baselineskip.html),  [`\baselinestretch`](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/latexdoc/baselineskip.html), [`\linespread`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30073/why-is-the-linespread-factor-as-it-is) come in handy in controlling the interline spacing. Each has its own speciality and circumstances of usage, as we can find in these discussions ([A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing), [B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13742/what-does-double-spacing-mean), [C](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30073/why-is-the-linespread-factor-as-it-is)).

If want to go for a ready made solution for controlling line spacing, packages like [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) come in quite handy (built-in commands like `\onehalfspacing` or `\setstretch` for more finer controls).

Anyway, my problem is a bit different. I have some text (both in paragraph and list mode) which I want to fill up exactly one page. To complicate the scenario, it may even contain equations and graphics. (Let us leave aside floats.)

If I want to solve the problem statically, all I will have to is to play with some value of `\baselineskip` (or  `\setstretch`) until satisfied. While this works good for most of the cases, I will have to go through the process again when I want to delete or add some texts.

Would it be possible to have a dynamic value for 
`\baselineskip` or  `\setstretch` so that my text always fills up one page? (Definitely within reasonable limits.)

Another idea will be to use a number of `\vfill`s between some pieces of texts. But I think that this technique is usable for cover pages only.

I am not putting here an MWE. I think that one is not applicable.

---

The problem is not a theoretical one, I am preparing some kind of handout which I want to fill-up exactly one page.

Comment: Do you want to adjust the line spacing within paragraphs? Or will adjusting space between paragraphs, and between text and equations etc. be enough?

Comment: @IanThompson Adjusting space only between paragraphs (and text and equations) may produce disproportionate results. I am looking for something which adjusts spaces all over the page, you know what I mean.

Comment: Please, in real document, adjust the inter-line space _as little as possible_, if even. There're people who seriously hate it. I have to claim that I do it myself, because I'm too lazy dealing with underfull pages by `<3pt` or so.

Comment: Is it an option to adjust the margins instead? E.g. you could automatically choose margins that precisely center your material on the page, with the dimensions of the text block determined by its length. (The TeXbook has several sample macros in this spirit, if I recall correctly.)

Comment: in addition to what's been suggested, if you always have exactly one page, and the amount of text decreases, you might want to consider using a larger type size so that the blank background doesn't overwhelm the type.  but i can't think of a way to do that automatically.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I understand what you are suggesting and I do follow this in most of the cases. But the scenario (which I can not divulge fully due to confidentiality reasons) do require me to prepare the document in the manner I have asked for.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add stretchability to `\baselineskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the page is filled up
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\addstretch}[1]{\addtolength{#1}{\fill}}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\addstretch{\baselineskip}
\addstretch{\abovedisplayskip}
\addstretch{\abovedisplayshortskip}
\addstretch{\belowdisplayskip}
\addstretch{\belowdisplayshortskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\kant*[1]
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\kant[2-3]

\newpage

\kant*[1]
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\kant[2]

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Using `\fill` overrides the `\vfil` inserted by `\newpage`.

[image]

It's easy to make a `onepage` environment:

```
\newenvironment{onepage}
  {\newpage\flushbottom
   \addstretch{\baselineskip}
   \addstretch{\abovedisplayskip}
   \addstretch{\abovedisplayshortskip}
   \addstretch{\belowdisplayskip}
   \addstretch{\belowdisplayshortskip}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
  {\newpage}
```

Here's the complete code with the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the page is filled up
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\addstretch}[1]{\addtolength{#1}{\fill}}
\newenvironment{onepage}
  {\newpage\flushbottom
   \addstretch{\baselineskip}
   \addstretch{\abovedisplayskip}
   \addstretch{\abovedisplayshortskip}
   \addstretch{\belowdisplayskip}
   \addstretch{\belowdisplayshortskip}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
  {\newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{onepage}
\kant*[1]
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\kant[2-3]
\end{onepage}

\begin{onepage}
\kant*[1]
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\kant[2]
\end{onepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Nothing to do with your solution, but your file as it is produces this error message, `(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/expl3/l3file.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ExplFileName 
                         
l.30 ...e}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}`. Anything from my version of LaTeX? Tested with lipsum. It is like a new toy for a child to see how the spaces adjust.

Comment: @MMA Since `kantlipsum` uses `expl3`, the error message probably means you have to update your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 20):

Just hope @egreg never sees this result

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{one two three four five six}
\def\b{\a\a\a\a\a\par\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a}

\flushbottom
\begin{document}
\setlength\baselineskip{\fill}
\setlength\lineskip{\fill}
\setlength\parskip{\fill}

\b\b

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you even need `\flushbottom`? raggedbottom only adds some `fil` which is infinitely smaller than your `fill` anyway ;-)

Comment: Well I started off timid (with finite stretch) but I got brave before posting:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Spent some time watching (playing actually) how the space adjusts when I add or delete texts. What do you do when get _two_ acceptable solutions?

Comment: @MMA If you get two acceptable solutions, and one is mine, then the _obvious_ course of action is surely to accept mine:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Give me some time to savor this sweet dillema.

Comment: @MMA oh no you gave it to egreg:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You know, an accepted solution means which best suited the OP... :-)

Answer (score 16):

Try this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}

\patchcmd\newpage{\vfil}{}{}{}

\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\baselineskip \the\baselineskip plus .1pt


\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\flushbottom` makes LaTeX fill the page to the bottom *on a page break*. The patch to `\newpage` is neccessary to make it work also for a one-page document.

The modification of `\baselineskip` is probably not as elegant as it could be and will vanish on font switches. You probably know more about modifying it properly than I do.

Note that `\parskip` has `1pt` of stretchability, so interline space stretches 1/10 the amount of inter-paragraph space.

Comment: only 1pt?, so timid:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not my decision, it's in the LaTeX sources. So I kept it for compatibility reasons ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke Are not the inter-paragraph spaces a bit out of proportion?

Comment: Well of course this depends on the amount of material on the page. If you require the page to be filled up completely, the space has to go somewhere. Of course, if you are using equations and suchlike, there will be more "stretch points". For instance, `\displayskip` has `3pt` of stretchability, so the space around equations will stretch three times as much as the inter-paragraph space. The `plus .1pt` component I put in `\baselinestretch` only fixes the relation of stretchability to 1:10. You get a different relation by using a different value.

Comment: @MMA If you use `\baselineskip \the\baselineskip plus .5pt` the inter-paragraph space is "only" double the inter-line space.

Answer (score 10):

Making `\baselineskip` stretchable is overkill, and it is **typographically poor practice** unless you're only generating a single page. If you have multiple pages, a flexible baselineskip will change the amount of black on the page which looks unpleasant, even for small changes.

You can use `\vfill` in any context, but I would recommend using as light a touch as possible: `\flushbottom` will ensure bottom-aligned text, suppressing the `\vfil` that is otherwise inserted at the bottom of the page and leaving you free to use `\vfil` for your own vertical space (or to exercise finer control with expressions like `10pt plus 1fil`).

I suggest you identify all places in your content where it's ok to add a bit of stretch, and arrange to have a `\vfil` in each one. That way the regular interlinear space (`\baselineskip`) can stay constant. Lists and the like already introduce stretchable space, but you may need to tweak that in order to get the whitespace to be evenly distributed.