# beamer, \vfill and itemize

Tags: beamer, spacing, positioning

I would like to place, in some frames, a text, on the bottom right of a beamer slide.
I created a command which places this text by `\vfill\hfill`. In a normal class (as article), it works perfectly. But with beamer, the `\vfill` does not seem to have the standard behavior.

Compare the frame 1 and 2 in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\def\position#1#2{\vfill\hfill #1-#2}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\position{2}{2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\position{2}{2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `beamer` uses `\vfill` at both ends to vertically center the frame contents.

Comment: Do you want to place the text specified by `\position` in the lower right corner of the frame? Then `\vfill\hfill` is certainly not the best way even for `article`.

Comment: why? what should be the best way?

Comment: in many case I want to put i the the lower right corner, but in some time, I want to put it between some other texte, so the \vill is perfect in my case.

Comment: @Maïeul , I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly but if you want your text to have exactly the same position from a slide to another, maybe you can try the eso-pic package ?

Comment: non @Alain I just want to have the normal behavior of \vfill. In many case, it's to have on the bottom right, but not in all.

Comment: You don't have to use the frame environment, in which case it will be formatted like a normal page (where \textwidth=\paperwidth and \textheight=\paperheight).

Comment: @JohnKormylo : I want it as a frame, not as a normal page.

Comment: This is possibly related, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148365/how-do-i-ask-beamer-to-exactly-fill-up-a-slide/159043#159043, in that use of your `\position` macro in conjunction with the approach there places the item in the lower right of the beamer slide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will agree with @egreg that this does not seem to be the right way to do what you intend. I think that @Peter Grill's answer is a better option. In any case, if you insist, here's what I suggest.

Beamer uses `\vfill` to vertically justify your slide.  You may think of it this way: there's a `\vfill` above your slide's contents and one more below them.  So, roughly speaking, the `\vfill` that you introduce only uses one third of the slide's vertical unused space.

To use all of that space, you need the next level of TeX's glue stretching:

```
\def\position#1#2{\vskip 0pt plus 1filll\hfill #1-#2}
```

This will leave you with no space at the top or the bottom of your slide, but it may be what you were looking for.

Comment: yes, it's working in many case, except when my slide is too big (but that implies I should change my slide).

Comment: thanks a lot. But I am still thinking that is linked to a none standard behavior of beamer.

Answer (score 5):

According to the `beamer` manual you can use the `textpos` package to position things absolutely on a page:

> **12.8 Positioning Text and Graphics Absolutely**
>
> Normally, beamer uses TEX’s normal typesetting mechanism to position text and graphics on the page. In certain situation you may instead wish a certain text or graphic to appear at a page position that is specified absolutely. This means that the position is specified relative to the upper left corner of the slide.
>   The package `textpos` provides several commands for positioning text absolutely and it works together with beamer. When using this package, you will typically have to specify the options `overlay` and perhaps `absolute`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\newcommand*{\XOffsetFromBottomRight}{-2.0em}%
\newcommand*{\YOffsetFromBottomRight}{2.0ex}%
\newcommand*{\BottomRightText}[2]{%
    \par%
    \begin{textblock*}{5.0cm}(\dimexpr\textwidth-\XOffsetFromBottomRight\relax,\dimexpr\textheight-\YOffsetFromBottomRight\relax)
        #1-#2%
    \end{textblock*}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\BottomRightText{2}{1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\BottomRightText{2}{2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: many thank. I have opted for the @nickie solution, but your solution works too.

Answer (score 3):

```
\vspace{\stretch{100}}
```

Will do something like this:

`\vfill`
(top part of slide)
`\vfill\vfill...\vfill` (thats the `\vspace{\stretch{100}}` part)
(bottom part of slide)
`\vfill`

and will therefore simulate almost the expected `\vfill` result.

You can now either change only the definiton of your \position command like this

```
\def\position#1#2{\vspace{\stretch{100}}\hfill #1-#2}
```

or define your own \myvfill for BEAMER usage

```
\def\myvfill{\vspace{\stretch{100}}}
\def\position#1#2{\myvfill\hfill #1-#2}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? What are the advantages to the both given answers? Only code writing without explaining is not very clear ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not really clear where one should put this code

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact use your macro with beamer if you use a `s`tretchable frame (possibly with a `\vfill` at the start if you want your frame to be centred):

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\def\position#1#2{\vfill\hfill #1-#2}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[s]
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\position{2}{2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[s]
\vfill
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\position{2}{2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However personally, I think it would be easier if you would attach your text to some already existing element at the bottom of the frame, e.g. the `navigation symbols` or the `footline`:

```
\documentclass[
  handout
]{beamer}

\newcommand{\position}[2]{
  \addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{{\color{black}\normalsize #1-#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\position{2}{2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\item a
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```