# Book-style page filling in article documentclass?

Tags: vertical-alignment, document-classes

Simple question. I feel like it should have a simple answer but I can't find anything.

The documentclass `book` (and default multicols) stretches content so that it fills the page. Now, I want to use this content in a document of mine that is typeset with the `article` documentclass.

If I use `book` and redefine the margins I get what I want, except that it changes `\sections` and `\subsections`, which doesn't look right for a formal lab report.

Comment: Hi and Welcome!

Comment: @Ryan: In which way does changing the margins change the sections etc? You should give us an example

Comment: you can specify `\flushbottom` (in the preamble).  the `article` class defaults to `\raggedbottom` unless `twocolumn` is in effect.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I guess he is talking of the numbering of sections, which will have a `0` in front.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Possibly, but this has nothing to do with the redefined margins but with a missing 'lead' chapter

Comment: possible duplicate: [How do I ask LaTeX to exactly fill up a page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147545/579)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I meant I can use the `geometry` package to remove the uneven margins that are made for binding, but that `\section{}` starts at 0.1 in the `book` environment, whereas I want it to start at 1. I didn't mean to sound like the margins were effecting the numbering, the `book` documentclass does that for the `\chapter{}` command, which is the first level in `book`.

@barbarabeeton That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! 

I already had the space designed to stretch and everything (lots of tables and minipages and figures) so dropping that in worked flawlessly. Thanks!