# Fill up a page by equations, and then switch to onecolumn

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

Similar question = [How do I ask LaTeX to exactly fill up a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147545/how-do-i-ask-latex-to-exactly-fill-up-a-page)

I want to fill up a page by several `equation`s because they come with automatic numbering.
I tried the `\lineskip\fill` trick but it is not perfect.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

    Some Lorem Ipsum here.

    \bgroup
    \lineskip\fill
    \def\bigbox#1 {
        \begin{equation}
            \vrule height#1cmdepth#1cmwidth3cm
        \end{equation}
    }
    \bigbox1
    \bigbox1
    \bigbox1
    \bigbox1
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
    \egroup

\onecolumn

    Here is one-column material.

\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I possibly align (6) and (10)?

Comment: In this case you have no `\baselineskip`s to add glue.  Try `\addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt plus 100fil minus 2pt}` instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I suppose `\lineskip` is used instead of `\baselineskip` because the equations are too high. Anyway I tried your code, (6) and (10) are not aligned.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No I want them evenly distributed. And the two columns here are both evenly distributed. But the problem is, (6) and (10) are not aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution puts the equation inside a `\vbox` with no gaps, then adds `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowsiplayskip` back on.  These get absorbed at the top and bottom of the page, but alas not before `\pagebreak` (which is used to avoid the `\vfil` from `\onecolumn`).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\def\bigbox#1 {\bgroup
    \parskip=0pt
    \ifvmode\else\par\fi
    \vskip\abovedisplayskip
    \noindent\vbox{\begin{equation}
        \vrule height#1cm depth#1cm width3cm
    \end{equation}\par
    \vskip-\belowdisplayskip
    \vskip\dp\strutbox}% end of \vbox
    \vskip\belowdisplayskip
    \egroup\noindent}

\begin{document}
    Some Lorem Ipsum here.

    \bgroup
    \lineskip=0pt plus 10pt minus 0pt

    \bigbox1
    \bigbox1
    \bigbox1
    \bigbox1 
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
    \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
%   \bigbox2
    \egroup
\vskip-\belowdisplayskip
\pagebreak
\onecolumn

    Here is one-column material.

    \the\abovedisplayskip

    \the\belowdisplayskip

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: It seems (11) is at page 2. If I comment out (11) it fails again.

Comment: Tried a different approach. The question is do you want it to look right, or are you just playing with equations and \onecolumn?

Comment: I want it to look right (i.e. it is not obviously wrong). It does not matter if (6) and (10) both touch the bottom line or both exceed the bottom line. As long as they are aligned I am satisfied. In my case (11), (12), etc are wide equations so I really need to switch to one-column mode between (10) and (11).

Comment: Here is another problem (sorry for being annoying): in your approach (7) does not touch the top boundary anymore. I would like to see how you can fix it. (It is not like I want the world burn. But I tried everything I know but it is difficult to deal with top and bottom boundary simultaneously.)

Comment: I did not want to have to put the equation into a box and emulate the trivlist behavior, but it was the only way to get the \vskips outside the list. BTW, much of the expansion is being done by \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip, not \lineskip