# Double line spacing, except in tables

Tags: tables, line-spacing

Extending the question [Double line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing) (as I'm new round here I don't seem to be able to comment), I'd like to use double spacing too. Except in tables, where I'd like to be able to leave that at single spacing, or specify a separate line spacing.

But I have a constraint: my LaTeX is being generated from MultiMarkdown via Pandoc, and so I don't get much control over the code. I do get to insert header code before the `\begin{document}`, so these lines do take effect:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

Is there a way of setting tables to be single spaced **in the header**?

If it matters, I believe the table package used in the generated source is `longtable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start of environment `longtable` can be redefined to add `\singlespacing`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\longtable{\par\singlespacing}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{longtable}{lp{10cm}}
    1&a\tabularnewline
    2&b\tabularnewline
    3&\lipsum[2]
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]