# Spacing between the lines

Tags: line-spacing

How to set the spacing (vertical) between two lines of the document? What is the standard spacing?

Comment: Standard spacing is `1`. You can use `setspace` package. Or do it by yourself with `\setstretch{1.2}` say. You can also change `\baselineskip`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Double line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819/5764)

Comment: The question is not absolutely clear to me; perhaps you’ll find what you’re looking for by searching for “linespread”?