# Double spacing when using classicthesis.sty

Tags: line-spacing, classicthesis

The answer provided in this question does not work with classicthesis: [Double line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing)

Specifically, using `setspace` and `\doublespacing` does not work. Using `\linespread` does but this introduces spacing in e.g. figure captions and tables too, which is not optimal.

Classicthesis can be found here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis

Since Classicthesis is used a lot for PhD theses, and a lot of these are required to be double spaced, I'm probably not the only one who's had this problem. Somebody had previously asked this question and it was (erroneously?) marked as a duplicate, linking back to the question above.

I'm not sure if I need to edit something in classicthesis.sty itself?

Comment: Hi and welcome, why shouldn't it work? It does very well. But keep in mind, `classicthesis` was designed for nice looking documents, even tought the implementations is a bit rough, the effort should be appreciated. Doublespacing and classicthesis should should contradict by common sense.

Comment: `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\chapter{matthew doublespace}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
`

Comment: Ah, my sincere apologies. I misplaced the `\doublespacing` and had it before the `\begin{document}` instead of after it, which I realised after reading your example. It now works. I am completely agreed about not normally changing the very nicely designed defaults, but sadly double spacing is a requirement from my university that I have no say in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a humanities thesis? Single-sided double-spaced not only looks awful but is a criminal waste of paper these days. I use

```
\setstretch{1.4}
```

which has been green-lighted as perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Anyway,so-called ‘double-spacing’ doesn't mean `setstretch{2}`, but `setstretch{1.6667}`

Answer (score 3):

The above answer by Leadbetter worked for me, but only when I added

`\usepackage{setspace}
 \setstretch{1.4}`

to the .sty file. It did not work when I added it to the main tex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although your solution surely works, it is always better to highlight that modifying original `.sty` files should be discouraged. As a solution, one can copy, rename those files before any modification and perform edits on the copies.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution, since I run into the same error, which was caused by something different.
Using the `setspace` usepackage is just fine, e.g.

`\usepackage[onehalfspacing
%doublespacing
]{setspace}`

When using in combination with `ClassisThesis` the `setspace` usepackage must be set **after** the call of `\usepackage{classicthesis}`. Otherwise only page margins are changed, but not the line spacing.