# Double Spacing for text but single spacing for everything else

Tags: line-spacing

I was typesetting my report when I encounter the problem about spacing between texts. The requirement for my report is double spacing. However, when I use \setstretch{2.0}, the whole document became double-spaced, including titles, captions and even quotes. Could anyone help me with the problem? Is there a solution such as a new-defined environment that solve the problem one and for all?
Thank you guys for your attention!

Comment: Package `setspace`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Could you elaborate it more? I am only  a rookie for Latex.

Comment: [Double line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/819) Heading off for lunch now. If you have further question, somebody else will help you.

Comment: `setspace` takes care of the side effects of `\setstretch` such as line spacing in footnotes. Just write the  `\doublespacing` at the beginning of your document, or, for a local use, `\begin{doublespace} … \end{doublespace}`. Note that double spacing desn't means `\setstretch{2}` but defaults to `\setstretch{1.667}`. I don't know what it does in titles, but in any case, it provides the `\singlespacing` switch. The documentation is interspersed within thre package code.

Comment: Thanks, Bernard! However, when I put \doublespacing before my chapters, the title of chapters are also double-spaced. How can I resolve that? It is very annoying to put \begin{doublespace} … \end{doublespace} for each subsubsections.

Comment: I would redefine the formatting of chapters with `titlesec`, incorporating a `\singlespacing` into the formatting (probably the argument that describes common formatting of label and title). Alternatively, with the `etoolbox` package, I would use `\pretocmd{\chapter}{\singlespacing}` and the like.

Comment: @user122049 Without a minimal working example (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4736) any answer to your questions maybe accidentally wight or rong. titlesec is a huge package and it will take you much more time to study the manual (`texdoc titlesec` on the command line), than to provide an example here.