# Line spacing in TeX

Tags: line-spacing

I am using `\font\preloaded=cmr9 \magnification=1200` in a TeX document. How  can I change the line spacing (from, say, 1 to 1.5) throughout the document?

Comment: `\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip`?

Comment: Why write with TeX, LaTeX is much more convenient?!

Comment: See also this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1299/21344

Comment: What do you think `\font\preloaded=cmr9` is doing?

Comment: @KeksDose: That's not the question ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OP wrote »TEX« and http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/21275/vonbrand edited it to »TeX« and added highlighting. If somebody with a reputation of 1 ask a beginners question about line spacing, you have to consider that he is not aware of the difference between TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: @KeksDose: Actually the highlighting was done by me, but I missed to change `TEX` as well ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can modify `\baselineskip` as in LaTeX: here's a complete example.

```
\font\preloaded=cmr9 \magnification=1200
\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip

Foodtongue grass tongue fish quiche mint tongue-slice grass food tongue-slice fish
English-muffin-tongue. Grass cherry chocolate tongue, maize mint pepper apple
pasta-melon Foodtongue, apple wonton enchilada\dots

\bye
```

Result:

[image]